# not in gzip format (Zlib::GzipFile::Error) - while decompressing the gzip file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, zlib

I am trying to decompress a file with following Ruby code.

```
File.open("file_compressed.gz") do |compressed|
  File.open("file_decomp","w") do |decompressed|
    gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(compressed)
    result = gz.read
    decompressed.write(result)
    gz.close
  end
end
```

But I am getting following error -

```
 not in gzip format (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
 ./features/support/abc/abc_file.rb:44:in `initialize'
```

When I decompress the same file using gzip command on Mac it produced the correct uncompressed output.
For following command I can see -

```
 $file file_compressed.gz
 file_compressed.gz: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)
```

Do I need to put any header data while I create the compressed file with Zlib? Because when I use the inflate method instead of the GzipReader I get following error -

```
 incorrect header check (Zlib::DataError)
  ./features/support/abc/abc_file.rb:69:in `inflate'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a platform that doesn't use `LF` delimiters, but `CR`+`LF`, you may need to open the file in binary mode for reading:

```
File.open("file_compressed.gz", "rb") do |compressed|
  # ...
end
```

This should also avoid interpreting the input stream as anything but 8-bit binary.

Be sure to open your output file the same way using `"wb"` as the flag.